# Python: Count how many process ID's are running for a given script

Tags: python, pid

I need to check to see if there are more than 5 Process ID's running for a given script in python. Particularly, What module/methods would you recommend using to check if there are 5 or more processes of the same script that you are trying to run?

i.e. my script will be hypothetically be called `pythonrules.py`. I want to get a processlist to figure out how many `pythonrules.py` scripts are currently running on my system, and `exit()` if the `processcount >= 5`.

Please note this will be running in a linux environment.

Comment: What platform(s) are you running this on? You may want to check out the `psutil` module

Comment: Linux, sorry I should have stated that earlier. I will update the question.

Comment: why `ps -A | grep pythonrules.py | wc -l` is not an option?

Comment: @marat, I'm wondering if there is a better way than using `subprocess` in python. I need this to run inside of python as it is part of a larger process.

Comment: Did you look at [process pools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)?